# Some special characters have rendering problem as a pdf file in LocalReport

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, render, rdlc

I am using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.dll to render my RDLC as a pdf file, but when i open pdf file with adobe reader i have a problem about some special Turkish characters.In pdf, they seem normal but when i try to use CTRL + F to search some words in the pdf file. I couldn't find these words. Even if my pdf file included these Turkish characters. Also, when i copy-paste these words into the file, i get characters like . It is interesting as i also use the same dll to render my RDLC as an excel file. I use same class same code and same method. I don't have this problem in an excel file.

I use `byte[] Render(string format);` method in WinForms.dll for rendering. Maybe some special character's ASCII code is out of range for byte array maybe because of this it couldn't render every characters for pdf format but i am not sure about this.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code?

Comment: Does this only happen in adobe reader or other pdf readers too?, which font are you using?

Comment: .NET strings are Unicode, not ASCII. There are no special characters. Squares like this appear if ASCII text is read using the wrong codepage, or when ASCII text is displayed on the screen using the wrong codepage. Where does the data come from? Does it come from a `varchar` or `nvarchar` field? How are the values retrieved?

Comment: Somehow, somewhere, ASCII text is stored instead of Unicode. Perhaps the database uses `varchar` fields instead of `nvarchar`, and the client uses a *different* collation than the database. Or perhaps the data was stored using the wrong collation to begin with.

Comment: @Bacon actually i have same problem for all pdf readers. I use many fonts in RDLC. Such as Roboto, Segoe UI Light, Roboto Condensed, Segoe UI, Segoe UI Black. Every fonts have same issue.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have a table in RDLC and this table's data come from mssql database. Mostly they are varchar field. Except this data, i have also static label field in RDLC. Labels have also same problem.

Comment: @srht81 the problem is using `varchar` in the first place. That's the type for ASCII text. The only way for it to work is for the column, web server *and* report definition to use the correct codepage, in this case Turkish. If the column's collation is eg Latin1, reading the data will always result in incorrect conversions.

Comment: The easiest and *cleanest* way to fix it is to change the type to `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

according to [microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/de-at/help/3152596/fix-unicode-characters-are-displayed-as-square-blocks-after-you-paste) there is an issue with special characters that is fixed in sql server 2014, the corresponding reportviewer dll would be the 2015 runtime.

maybe you should upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My application generates PDFs using LocalReport.
My solution was:
1- Modify the RDLC XML schema to use the 2016 version. Change what you have for this.

```
<Report xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns: rd = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">.
```

Then, modify the schema, it is no longer the same as previous versions (DataSources go up ...)

2- Remove `<EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>` from DeviceInfo.

With these changes, I got the special characters painted and printed well.